# When is a java exception thrown

Tags: java

Please see below pseudocode method. If the call to `readUrls()` throws an exception, doesn't that mean that `closeConnection()` will not be executed and program flow will return to the method that calls `getdata()`?

Thanks

```
getdata() throws Exception
{
     setup();
     readUrls();
     closeConnection();
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your assumption is correct. To avoid this you can do something like this:

```
getdata() throws Exception
{
    setup();
    try { 
        readUrls();
    } finally {
        closeConnection();
    }
}
```

Comment: But then the `throws` clause is probably superfluous.

Comment: No, it's not: this exception is still thrown.

Answer (score 2):

yes, if `readUrls()` throws an exception the flow will return to the method calling `getdata()`, where the same thing will happen, until:

- there is a `catch` block, where the exception is handled
- the exception bubbles up to the main method / to the `run` method of the thread.

Answer (score 2):

When an exception is thrown, the current method call is interrupted and returns immediately. Use a try-catch-finally pattern for closing connections (with closeConnection() in the finally-statement))

Answer (score 1):

It depends if you have not handled exception in `readUrls()` then Yes what you are saying is correct. That means you do not have `try...catch` in `readUrls()` method.